# how can I make a clickable image in react without showing the hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tags

this should make a clickable image but apparently the hyperlink is showing next to the image.

```
<div>
  <a href = {link}><img src= {image} alt= 'icon' />{link}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do away with the <a> and put an onClick handler on the img itself, handle any page movement or effect from the handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove {link} after the image tag:

```js
<div>
  <a href = {link}>
    <img src= {image} alt= 'icon' />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: {link} renders the *string* stored in *variable* "link". When it renders in an *href attribute* a link is generated, when it renders in *href content* it renderes as *linked text*